# Modularity - design patterns - Architecture

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, responsive-design, modularity

I'm trying to implement modularity system (J2EE) to allow changes of the type modules/plugins/add ons. 
I want to know how to start, what approach I should follow.
Are there any new design patterns for this type of system ?
or do I need a new technology (message bus, osgi) ?
Thanks in advance
Mhadjis

Answer (score 0):

Spring would be a good starting point. Spring context files let you specify most of the architecture in XML and the replace them later. This makes for a very modular architecture. Now in terms of being able to write "plugins" like where a user can provide a jar file and it hooks into the app dynamically that is something you'd have to roll yourself. However, Spring could help you there again by providing a lot of tools for abstracting out the configuration of plugins and loading them (loading them as Spring contexts).